# LeetCode: Diameter of a binary tree

Tags: python, depth-first-search

This code runs correctly for 100/104 test cases. but i dont know why and where does the code fail to incorporate for the remaining 4 cases. Please find the image of the problem and error case in this post.

```
# class TreeNode:
#     def __init__(self, val=0, left=None, right=None):
#         self.val = val
#         self.left = left
#         self.right = right
class Solution:
    def diameterOfBinaryTree(self, root: Optional[TreeNode]) -> int:
        left_root = root.left   # left root of the root node
        right_root = root.right # right side of the root node
        
        def dfs(root: Optional[TreeNode]) -> int: # to calculate the height
            if not root:
                return 0
            
            left = dfs(root.left)
            right = dfs(root.right)
            
            return 1 + max(left, right)
        
        left_depth = dfs(left_root) # finding depth for both sides of it
        right_depth = dfs(right_root)
        
        return left_depth + right_depth # adding the heights
```

[image: Error is shown here]

Question is as follows:

[image: this is the question]

Comment: Where is the Problem `description`?   It's impossible to help you debug w/o knowing -1) the problem, 2) the failed inputs (sample).

Comment: please take a look again..thanks.